A quote attributed to Luther about "issues which deal specifically with your time"
I saw this quote:
“If you preach the gospel in all aspects with the exception of the issues which deal specifically with your time, you are not preaching the gospel at all.” — Martin Luther
What was the original context?
Was the original in Latin or German?

@NigelJ that is technically another quote though (“We need to hear the gospel everyday because we forget it every day”) but I guess the problem is similar.

Been reading Luther many years and did not come across this type of quote as he would usually just consider the basic gospel as all that was ever needed for all generations. however he could also easily have said this when dealing with issues of his day, like the peasant revolt or heavy drinking by Germans, he often adds exclamation marks to most everything he said. Gotta love a guy like that! Though I could not find this quote in the complete works of Martin Luther in English unfortunately. There are many miscellaneous works not translated.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

I haven’t found an answer, but I found another version attributed to Martin Luther: “A gospel that does not deal with the issues of the day is not the gospel at all.”

Another person, while also unable to find the source, thought that it didn't sound like Luther, but more like Barth or Bonhoeffer
